# String parenthesis in right order and valid properly closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Need some help trying to come up with a java utility that returns true/false if string contains the parenthesis and are in order of precedence and properly closed if nested **{**, **[**, **(** i.e. ( should be inside [ and same way [ should be inside { if all three present.

```
[a(b)c]    // here have only [ & ( and it's valid as ( is nested inside [
{a[b(c)d]e}  // here have all {, [, ( and it's valid as ( is nested insdie [ and [ is nested inside {
(abc)  // is valid as only have (
{a}+[b]+[c]+(d)  // is valid as no nesting but individually closed
{a[b]c}  // is valid as nesting following the order [ is inside { even though ( is missing
{a[b[c(d)e]f]g}  // here have all {, [, ( and it's valid as ( is nested inside [ and [ is nested inside {


(a[b{c}d]e)   // this is invalid as nesting is not in order should be {, [, (
{9+{(3-3)}+1}  // this is invalid as nesting should be in order {, [, (
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a stack, you start iterating the string and every time you find a parenthesis you check it with the last element of the stack:

- if the stack is empty and you have an open parenthesis insert it into the stack
- if the stack has an open parenthesis at the top and you have a closed one then they must be of the same type (so you can remove the last element in the stack) otherwise you return false
- if the stack has an open parenthesis at the top and you have an open one, check that it is regular, if so, insert it into the stack otherwise you will return false

If all goes well and you manage to empty the stack and scroll through the complete list you can return true